# Android app download pattern involving same image on different devices/screens

Tags: android, image, size, apk, drawable

Let us suppose that I made an android app that has an image in it.

I had kept the same image of different sizes in xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi Drawable folders.

When a 'hdpi android phone' downloads my app, will it it download the image from all the Drawable folders or just the 'hdpi' Drawable folder ?

I wanted to know if using separate images for separate screen types increases the app size or not.

Comment: It has to since it can't know which pictures are for what. You can have a large icon and a small icon, one used for the application's shortcut and the other to display in your start up screen. The software doesn't differentiate. Usually you will target either tablets, phones or TV's anyway and there's no need to provide all sizes of pictures just because the folders exist. If no picture is found, it will simply look for a larger one in the next bucket and scale it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apk will be downloaded with all the internal resources(Images,raw directory etc..) and your APK should not be above 50MB if your APK size exceeds  this limit you may have to use seperate Expansion files. [Description Here](http://Http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

**EDIT:**
You can try Multiple APK Support if your apk size exceeds 50Mb limit and you still want to embed all resources inside your APK [Described Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes the download of the APK always includes all resources you have included.